# web client python http

Tags: python, sockets, http, webclient

I have this code in python that shows a http response, using a socket. At this point i can identify the status code, and print the message. but now i want to prepare my code to act to the different http responses, like one in particular, like 302, witch is moved permanently, so my code needs to make a new GET method to the new location.

what's the best way of doing this?

PS: cant use a http library

```
from socket import * 

#response dictionary
my_dict={200:'ok',302:'moved',404:'error'}

from socket import * 

#ask inputs
target_host = input("Enter the url: ")#localhost
target_dir = input("Enter the  path: ")#/index.html or /
target_port = input("Enter the port number: ")#80

# create a socket object 
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  # create an INET (IPv4), STREAMing socket (TCP)
 
# connect the client 
client.connect((target_host,int(target_port)))  
 
# send some data 
request = "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % (target_dir, target_host)

#Send data to the socket.
client.send(request.encode())  

# receive some data 
data = b''
while True: #while data
    buffer = client.recv(2048) #recieve a 2048 bytes data from socket
    if not buffer or buffer=='\n': #no more data, break
        break
    data += buffer #concatenate buffer data
    
client.close() #close connection

status = -1  #init status
word = data.split() #split data in a array of words
try:
    status = int(word[1])#cast data[i] 
except:
    pass

#print data
print("status code: " , status)
print("server reply: " , data.decode())
```

Comment: *"what's the best way of doing this?"* - This is very unspecific and does not actually show a specific problem you have. The easiest way (which for many is the best) is of course to use a library. Since you cannot do this you should read and understand the actual HTTP standard, learn from this on how to parse the response and what the semantics exactly are and act accordingly. If this fits your description of "best" - who knows. The "best" way in your mind might that somebody does all the coding for you but this is not how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resolving multiple redirects and then getting the server ip using dns resolution of final url , you can directly get the server ip using socket.gethostbyname and then create a connection to the desired ip .

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
s.connect((ip_addr, 443))  # using https port
```

You can enter the value present in variable ***ip_addr*** in your browser and check , it would be redirected to google.com